# Flutter with Firebase Storage - Trying to upload image (jpg, png, anything) fails without an error

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

In my Flutter application, I've been trying to upload a simple image.jpg, however, even if client side no error is shown and the image gets uploaded, on the console it stays on the upload path for a few seconds before the server transfers it to an "images" folder and appends "_1000x1000" to it, and not being able to preview it nor download it. The path changes and the image gets corrupted. My code and the result below:

```dart
var result = await FilePicker.getFile(type: FileType.IMAGE);
if (result != null) {
   var ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("test").child(basename(result.path));
   print(ref.path);
   ref.putFile(result);
}
```

The print returns this path: "test/miau.jpeg" and the upload tast (putFile) returns no error whatsoever. I'm expecting the path to remain the one I uploaded and the image to be usable, none of which are happening.

I use the following plugins:

```xml
cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
redux: ^4.0.0
flutter_redux: ^0.6.0
cloud_firestore: ^0.12.11
firebase_auth: ^0.15.1
flutter_login: ^1.0.4
flare_splash_screen: ^3.0.0
google_sign_in: ^4.0.14
flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0
flutter_typeahead: ^1.7.0
firebase_storage: ^3.1.1
file_picker: ^1.4.3+1
path: ^1.6.4
```

[image: The upload result]

Comment: Please edit the question to answer: What does the print statement actually print?  What is the value of `basename(result.path)`? Does `putFile()` return anything helpful, such as an error?  What exactly are you expecting to happen that's different than what you observe?

Comment: @DougStevenson Edited now, I hope it can be answered.

Comment: So you're saying that you have a file called "test/miau.jpg", but in the consle it appears as "sample_1000x1000.jpg"? That doesn't seem possible.  Are you sure you're looking at the right things?

Comment: I also note that you're uploading to `.child("test")`, but in the console are showing the `images` folder. That combined with the filename extension makes me wonder if you've installed the image resizer extension by any chance?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen OMG that is it! It's that extension, I installed it to reduce size on the storage. Btw, I actually uploaded other names but in frustration I kept changing the code, creating those mistakes. Could you answer this question with that to prevent anyone else from making this mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed two things about your question:

- You're uploading to `.child("test")`, but in the console are showing the `images` folder.
- The file in the `images` folder has a `_1000x1000` suffix.

That combination makes me think of the Image Resizer extension. Do you have that installed by any chance, and configured to write its output to `images`?